# Как лучше и правильно написать js OOP код?

Tags: javascript, ооп, классы, инспекция-кода

Немного почитал , посмотрел ООП по js. Попробовал сделать небольшой пример кода. Правильно ли так писать? Можно ли совмещать простые, разные функции с классами и т.д. как в моем коде, или совсем плохо я уже написал? Можете подсказать что может не так написал, или что то добавить для простоты?

Еще чуть вопросов. Если у меня 3 разных паб-окна, то можно написать все методы в одном классе или написать только главные функции (открыть,закрыть) и уже наследовать его для каждого нового класса с новыми методами?

```
class PupMenu {
   constructor(pubuP, classActive) {
      this.pubuP = pubuP;
      this.classActive = classActive;
   }

   exit() {
      //ЗАКРЫВАЕТ ОКНО
   }

   open() {
      //ОТКРЫВАЕТ ОКНО
   }

   slideLeft() {
      //Переключить фото назад
   }
   slideRigth() {
      //Переключить фото вперед
   }

   sendRequest() {
      //Отправить сообщения
   }
}

const btn1 = document.querySelector('.btn1')
const btn2 = document.querySelector('.btn2')
const btn3 = document.querySelector('.btn3')

const pub1 = document.querySelector('.pub1')
const pub2 = document.querySelector('.pub2')
const pub3 = document.querySelector('.pub3')

const arrowLeft = document.querySelector('.arrowLeft')
const arrowRigth = document.querySelector('.arrowRigth')

const send = document.querySelector('.send')

let pupWindowOne = new PupMenu(pub1, 100)
let pupWindowTwo = new PupMenu(pub2, 400)
let pupWindowThree = new PupMenu(pub3, 40)

btn1.addEventListener('click', () => {
   pupWindowOne.open()
})

btn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
   pupWindowTwo.open()
})

btn3.addEventListener('click', () => {
   pupWindowThree.open()
})

arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', pupWindowTwo.slideLeft)

arrowRigth.addEventListener('click', pupWindowTwo.slideRigth)

function sendMs(e) {
   if (e.target...) {
      pupWindowThree.sendRequest()
   }
}
```

Comment: В целом - нормально. Но лучше подписываться на события тоже в классе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы делал код примерно таким (его еще можно улучшить - cделать короче и гибче):

```
class PupMenu {
   constructor(options) {
      const {btnClass, pubClass, send, classActive} = options
      this.classActive = classActive;
      this.btn = document.querySelector(btnClass)
      this.pub = document.querySelector(pubClass)
      this.send = send;
      btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
         this.open()
      })
   }
   exit() {/*ЗАКРЫВАЕТ ОКНО*/}
   open() { /*ОТКРЫВАЕТ ОКНО*/}
   slideLeft() {/*Переключить фото назад */}
   slideRigth() {/*Переключить фото вперед*/}
   sendRequest() {/*Отправить сообщения */}
}

const send = document.querySelector('.send')

let pupWindowOne = new PupMenu({
   buttonClass:'.btn1',
   pubClass: '.pub1',
   send,
   classActive: 100 
})

let pupWindowTwo = new PupMenu({
    buttonClass: '.btn2',
    pubClass: '.pub2', 
    send,
    classActive: 400
 })

let pupWindowThree = new PupMenu({
   buttonClass:'.btn3',
   pubClass: '.pub3',
   send,
   classActive: 40
})

const arrowLeft = document.querySelector('.arrowLeft')
const arrowRigth = document.querySelector('.arrowRigth')
arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', pupWindowTwo.slideLeft)
arrowRigth.addEventListener('click', pupWindowTwo.slideRigth)

function sendMs(e) {
   if (e.target...) {
      pupWindowThree.sendRequest()
   }
}
```

по второй части вопроса: https://javascript.info/static-properties-methods

Comment: Прочитал чутька, не очень понял, типу если надо с определённого класса взять метод в другой класс, тогда просто его сделать статическим и все? правильно понял?:

Comment: Статические методы такие которые не связаны с конкретным экземпляром класса но логически относятся к области деятельности класса.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/static-properties-methods

Comment: Я понял, а не проще когда создавать новый класс просто наследовать через  extends то что надо с другогу класса?

Comment: Наследование класов это уже про другое, про расширение функионала, а статика нужна для каких-то методов которые грубо говоря могли бы просто валятся где-то рядом с классом

Comment: В одном ответе не возможно описать все кейсы которые можно применять в программировании так как все специфично от задач, где-то одно лучше где-то другое, и разговаривать об этом можно бесконечно)

Comment: Я понял спс), а если не задано ничего, то метод в классе по стандартному private? и без задавания статичного уже никак его не вызвать кроме своего классу?

Comment: Приватности в js нет, по крайней мере настоящей, а второй вопрос не понял

Comment: Просто смотрел ангулар там тайпСкрипт, и есть приват, паблик, вот думал в ооп js юзать. Ну второй вопрос, если я не задам статик в методе, то его нельзя будет никак застоговать в других классах?

Comment: По своей сущности статические методы мало чем отличаются от простых функций но в отличие от тех их вызывают через имя класса, который можно даже не иницализировать например так:  PupMenu.close(menu) - экземпляр передается в аргументе а PupMenu - имя класса а не объекта созданного на его основе (не экземпляр в общем)

Comment: про ангулар - это просто клон  С# )) - автор тот же, но это "фейковый язык" исключительно для удобства типизаций и прочего (без транспиляции он не живет) и приватность он по итогу не дает, просто позволяет это контролировать при написании кода. В общем желаю успехов в обучении. Все таки тут не чат)